# How to set up input names to receive an array of hashes in params?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, input, hash, parameters

For the life of me, I can't remember how I did something like this before:

Params:

```
fieldname: {
 0 => { foo: 'bar'},
 1 => { foo2: 'bar2'}
}
```

I've tried several variations of `formname[]` and `formname[foo][]` but all I get is internal server errors. Any help?

Ideally, I'd like to see:

```
some_field: {
 username: { id: 'this', live: '1' },
 another_name: { id: 'that', live: '0' },
}
```

Something tells me that's not possible though.

Comment: Can you try this `some_field[#{@user.name}]["id", "live"]", [#{@user.id}, #{@user.live}]`

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like to me, is you can use a class such as

```
class foo_field
```

and make a separate array/list/enum whatever suits your best option. Assign the input to a __TEMP variable and then add it to your array. You could also gain your input through this class.

Comment: I'm more confused about how the `<input>` tags need to be set up to send more than one item of nested data

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)  Here is a good reference to the input tags